# Soundproofing my bedroom door

Tags: sound-proofing

What are the ways that I can use to soundproof my door so as whenever it closes it gives the maximum possible sound reduction (depending on the door, I know walls etc play a big part as-well but currently I cannot do anything about those). What I want is sound not getting instead of not getting out but I suppose you cannot have one without the other.

Comment: What sort of sound do you need to deal with? Traffic, music, machinery, voice? How much quieter do you hope to make it? It is never easy to reduce sound transmission, but there are specific approaches depending on what you are trying to do. In some cases, soundproofing the barrier isn't the best solution, there are other approaches which can improve the perceived sound level reduction

Comment: One product I've seen that may help is "Acoustidoor" but I haven't tried it. I like Jason's recommendations below. Link to Acoustidoor: https://residential-acoustics.com/shop/soundproofing/acoustidoor/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short of replacing it with a sealed, sound-proof door, I suppose you could throw some foam on it e.g. [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0002F78UI/ref=cm_cd_asin_](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002F78UI) and make sure gaps around the door are sealed; there are kits e.g. http://www.acousticalsolutions.com/door-seal-kits or something simpler to install like http://www.audimutesoundproofing.com/door-seal-kit.aspx. If you don't seal the gaps anything you do to the door will have minimal effect.

You may also be able to get *some* relief by just hanging some thick fabric over the door. Make sure it covers the entire door frame plus some, and all the way down the floor. It could act is a baffle of sorts, although I would not expect too much.

If sound is coming through the walls or vents, don't be surprised if you can still hear most of it.